# Navigation Back Button not hidden in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Do you know why the back button still showing after I wrote

```
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

it seem that Xcode doesn't read it correctly.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var goToHome: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Welcome(gotoSomewhere: $goToHome)
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $goToHome) { Home() }
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) //HERE IS THE NAVIGATIONBAR HIDDEN
        }
    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

I tried to write an NavigationLink but then shows me the alert:

> ... was deprecated in iOS 16.0: use NavigationLink(value:label:)
> inside a NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This modifier `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` should be on home.

`Home().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`

And yes the NavigationLink will be deprecated in the future, it's up to you whether it's important or not to include at the moment in your app.